# python formatting strings to ignore indentation whitespace

Tags: python, string, formatting

I have a class with instance attributes a,b,c. I used textwrap but it doesnt work.

```
 def __str__(self):
    import textwrap.dedent
    return textwrap.dedent(
    """#{0}
    {1}
    {2}
    """.format(self.a,self.b,self.c)
```

However, this is not working, and I am getting output like

```
a
        b
        c
```

Comment: `textwrap.dedent` gets rid of *common leading whitespace*. This means that each line must have the same whitespace in front of it. Clearly, your first line, `"#{0}...` does not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you render a string with `"""`, both newlines AND whitespaces are counted. If you want this to work without dedent, your code should look like this:

```
def __str__(self):
   return """#{0}
{1}
{2}
""".format(self.a,self.b,self.c)
```

Otherwise, the tabs before `{1}` and `{2}` are in the string as well. Alternatively, you could use:

```
"#{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n".format(self.a,self.b,self.c)
```

Regarding dedent and why it's not working, note this line from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent):

> the lines "  hello" and "\thello" are considered to have no common leading whitespace.

So if you want dedent to work, you need each line to start the same, so your code should be:

```
    return textwrap.dedent(
    """\
    #{0}
    {1}
    {2}
    """.format(self.a,self.b,self.c))
```

And in this case each line starts with `\t`, which `dedent` recognizes and removes.

Answer (score 3):

Do it like this:

```
from textwrap import dedent

def __str__(self):
    return textwrap.dedent("""\
        #{0}
        {1}
        {2}
        """.format(self.a,self.b,self.c))
```

Answer (score 0):

`textwrap.dedent` strips *common leading whitespace* (see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent)). If you want this to work, you'll need to do something like this:

```
def __str__(self):
    S = """\
        #{0}
        {1}
        {2}
    """
    return textwrap.dedent(S.format(self.a, self.b, self.c))
```

Comment: Thanks. I totally missed that.